# PHP Unfinished file uploading executes the entire script

Tags: php, file-upload

I created a class for form transaction and one of its method is for file uploading.
The class contains public methods which returns $this to be used for method chaining and one of it is for the file upload.

Code:

```
public function uploadFiles()
{
    $aFiles = $this->formatFiles($this->aFiles['file']);

    foreach ($aFiles as $sKey => $mValue) {
        $this->checkFileType($mValue['name']);
        $mUploadResult = file_uploader($mValue['tmp_name'], $mValue['name'], $mValue['size'], $this->sFileDir, 600000000);
        if ($mUploadResult) {

            $aFields = array(
                'parent',
                'file',
                'file_v',
                'type',
                'download'
            );

            $aData = array(
                $this->iParentNum,
                $mUploadResult,
                $mValue['name'],
                1,
                0
            );

            $this->insertDB($this->sTableFil, $aFields, $aData);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

$this->aFiles consists of $_FILES from PHP.

Problem:

When trying to upload file with large size (e.g. 500MB), it will upload but it will stop around 90% above then it will continue the script in which the variables to be initialized on the next method were not initialized which results to NULL value.

Method chain execution:

```
$oBoardWriteSaveNAdmin = new boardWriteSaveNAdmin($USER_ID, $USER_NAME, $dbs);

$oBoardWriteSaveNAdmin->setRequests()
    ->setData()
    ->connectToDB()
    ->getMember()
    ->getTableAuthority()
    ->processData()
    ->executeMode()
    ->uploadFiles()
    ->redirect();
```

Tried:

I tried to adjust the PHP.ini as mentioned in some pages.
PS: the values here are sample, I adjusted it in mine

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

even tried to include this codes at the top of the file of the class created,
PS: the values here are sample, I adjusted it in mine

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Comment: you are still allowing only max 10M files. Try `post_max_size = 1G` and also `upload_max_filesize 1G`.

Comment: I don't think you can adjust these parameters with `ini_set()`, because PHP doesn't start running the script until after it has decided whether to allow the upload.

Comment: If you can't access your `php.ini` you can try set the values via `.htaccess`.

Comment: @bansi i mentioned there that it's just a sample but i put a 600M and tried a 550M file to upload still the same

Comment: did you restart web server after changing the value in ini file? also check `phpinfo()` to see what configuration is being used.

Comment: yes i did check...